# Set partitions into k groups (including the NULL set) in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics, python-itertools, sage

there a few posts like this one
[I have a list of numbers, how to generate all unique k-partitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317360/i-have-a-list-of-numbers-how-to-generate-all-unique-k-partitions)

but i'd like to know if there are some new efficient libraries to solve this problem (`itertools` ? `sagemath` ?)

I have a list of numbers, how to generate all unique ordered k-partitions?
for example, if I have `[1,2,3,4,5]` and k=3

`[[1,2],[3],[4,5]]` is such a partition
but `[[4,5],[3],[1,2]]` is also such a partition

i would also like to include the NULL set as a possible set among the k subset for example

```
[[2,3],[],[1,4,5]]
```

the order matters between

```
[[1,2],[3],[4,5]]
```

and `[[4,5],[3],[1,2]]`

but [[2,1],[3],[5,4]] is considered the same as [[1,2],[3],[4,5]] if you follow me...

As far as I know, `OrderedSetPartitions(5,3)` from Sagemath will not provide the answer to my question because its excluding the NULL set

EDIT: here is a (non optimized at all) attempt to solve naively this problem using SAGEMATH

```
def OrderedSetPartitions_0(A,k):

    cols={i for i in range(k)}
    # returns the list of k-OrderedSetPartitions of A, allowing for the empty set
    s=Subsets(cols).list()
    res=[]
    count=0
    P=[OrderedSetPartitions(A,i) for i in range(k+1)]

    for sub in s:
           print("sub=")
           print(sub)

           tmp=[ {} for i in range(k)]
           c=sub.cardinality()
           for part in P[c]:
               print("part=")
               print(part)
               for i in range(c):
                   tmp[sub[i]]=part[i]

               print("tmp=")
               print(tmp)

               res=res.append([tmp])
               # res = res.append(tmp) # tried this too
               print("res=")
               print(res)
               count=count+1
    return(res)
    # print(count)

A=range(3)
k=2
A
P=[OrderedSetPartitions(A,i) for i in range(k+1)]
# note that P[2].list is a list of list !
P[2].list()
```

> ```
> [[{0, 1}, {2}],
>  [{0, 2}, {1}],
>  [{1, 2}, {0}],
>  [{0}, {1, 2}],
>  [{1}, {0, 2}],
>  [{2}, {0, 1}]]
> ```

```
myset=OrderedSetPartitions_0(A,k)
```

I get this error message, and I admit I don't get it at all, because it looks fine when coding,
but somehow res seems to be "None" instead of []

> ```
> sub=
> {}
> sub=
> {0}
> part=
> [{0, 1, 2}]
> tmp=
> [{0, 1, 2}, {}]
> res=
> None
> sub=
> {1}
> part=
> [{0, 1, 2}]
> tmp=
> [{}, {0, 1, 2}]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "_sage_input_21.py", line 10, in <module>
>     exec compile(u'open("___code___.py","w").write("#
> ```
>
> -*- coding: utf-8 -*-\n" + *support*.preparse_worksheet_cell(base64.b64decode("bXlzZXQ9T3JkZXJlZFNldFBhcnRpdGlvbnNfMChBLGsp"),globals())+"\n");
>   execfile(os.path.abspath("***code***.py"))
>         File "", line 1, in
>
> ```
>   File "/private/var/folders/gm/z065gk616xg6g0xgn4c7_bvc0000gn/T/tmpryfYOj/___code___.py", line 2, in <module>
>     exec compile(u'myset=OrderedSetPartitions_0(A,k)
>   File "", line 1, in <module>
>
>   File "/private/var/folders/gm/z065gk616xg6g0xgn4c7_bvc0000gn/T/tmpSH_9LF/___code___.py", line 27, in OrderedSetPartitions_0
>     res=res.append([tmp])
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
> ```

the problem is about aggregating the list into res. if i put a sharp to all the lines involving res i can enumerate the output correctly

EDIT:
thanks for your answers

actually i changed `res=res.append(tmp)` to `res.append(tmp)`
i get the enumeration right when doing `print(tmp)`

```
[{0, 1, 2}, {}, {}] [{}, {0, 1, 2}, {}] [{}, {}, {0, 1, 2}] [{0, 1}, {2}, {}] [{0, 2}, {1}, {}] [{1, 2}, {0}, {}] [{0}, {1, 2}, {}] [{1}, {0, 2}, {}] [{2}, {0, 1}, {}] [{0, 1}, {}, {2}] [{0, 2}, {}, {1}] [{1, 2}, {}, {0}] [{0}, {}, {1, 2}] [{1}, {}, {0, 2}] [{2}, {}, {0, 1}] [{}, {0, 1}, {2}] [{}, {0, 2}, {1}] [{}, {1, 2}, {0}] [{}, {0}, {1, 2}] [{}, {1}, {0, 2}] [{}, {2}, {0, 1}] [{0}, {1}, {2}] [{0}, {2}, {1}] [{1}, {0}, {2}] [{2}, {0}, {1}] [{1}, {2}, {0}] [{2}, {1}, {0}]
```

but strangely res is wrong , there must be some side effects

```
[[{0, 1, 2}, {}, {}],
 [{}, {0, 1, 2}, {}],
 [{}, {}, {0, 1, 2}],
 [{2}, {0, 1}, {}],
 [{2}, {0, 1}, {}],
 [{2}, {0, 1}, {}],
 [{2}, {0, 1}, {}],
 [{2}, {0, 1}, {}],
 [{2}, {0, 1}, {}],
 [{2}, {}, {0, 1}],
 [{2}, {}, {0, 1}],
 [{2}, {}, {0, 1}],
 [{2}, {}, {0, 1}],
 [{2}, {}, {0, 1}],
 [{2}, {}, {0, 1}],
 [{}, {2}, {0, 1}],
 [{}, {2}, {0, 1}],
 [{}, {2}, {0, 1}],
 [{}, {2}, {0, 1}],
 [{}, {2}, {0, 1}],
 [{}, {2}, {0, 1}],
 [{2}, {1}, {0}],
 [{2}, {1}, {0}],
 [{2}, {1}, {0}],
 [{2}, {1}, {0}],
 [{2}, {1}, {0}],
 [{2}, {1}, {0}]]
```

The first 3 lines are correct, then it starts to diverge with what i get with `print(tmp)`. its very strange to me because there is no instruction between `print(tmp)` and `res.append(tmp)` !!!!!

Comment: The error you saw is caused by `res=res.append([tmp])`. The list method `append` modifies the list in place, it doesn't return a value. So `res` got assigned to None as the result. Just drop that assignment (though I think there may be other issues with the code you have there.)

Comment: Two more things: you need to [create a fresh copy of tmp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802) when appending it, because subsequent modifications will affect what you have already appended. Use `res.append(tmp[:])`. Also, `{}` [is not empty set](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6130374), it's an empty dict. Use `set()` or `Set()` for empty set

Comment: thank you very much, this is indeed the reason of my "bug"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution in Sagemath, using NumPy arrays and itertools. The idea is same as in your code: create OrderedSetPartitions and beef them up with empty sets. To do this without too many loops, NumPy arrays are used: the key part is `partitions[:, s] = P` where certain columns of a 2D array `partitions`, initially filled with empty sets, are replaced by nonempty sets coming from OrderedSetPartitions.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
A = Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])        # Sage set, not Python set
k = 3                           # number of elements in partition
all_partitions = np.array(OrderedSetPartitions(A, k).list())
for i in range(k-1, 0, -1):
    P = np.array(OrderedSetPartitions(A, i).list()) if i > 1 else [[A]]
    for s in combinations(range(k), i):
        partitions = np.empty((len(P), k), dtype=object)
        partitions[:, :] = [[Set()]]
        partitions[:, s] = P
        all_partitions = np.vstack((all_partitions, partitions))
print all_partitions
```

The output is a double NumPy array. You can return `all_partitions.tolist()` if a Python list is desired.

#### Technicalities

Sage sets (created with `Set([1,2,3])`) and Python sets (created with `set([1,2,3])` or `{1,2,3,4,5}`) are objects of different classes. Within Sagemath, the output looks better for Sage sets: they are shown as {1,2,3} while Python sets are displayed as `set([1,2,3])`. For this reason, Sage sets are to be preferred within Sagemath. Also, OrderedSetPartitions returns Sage sets.

But it takes a bit more effort to get NumPy to play along with Sage sets: in particular, I couldn't get `np.full` to accept empty Sage set `Set()` as a filling object. This is the reason for using `np.empty` and then filling it in.

A similar issue is responsible for the case `i == 1` being treated differently: NumPy tries to cast `[[Set([1,2,3,4,5])]]` to a three-dimensional array of numbers instead of a two-dimensional array containing one Sage set object.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have made an edit. I'd like to know the reason of my bug if you can help on it as well. Thanks